# FabricJS double click on objects

Tags: fabricjs

I am trying to perform a special action whenever the user double clicks any object located inside the canvas. I have read the docs and not found any `mouse:dblclick`-like event in the documentation. I tried doing something like:

`fabric.util.addListener(fabric.document, 'dblclick', callback);`

Which does trigger the dblclick event but does not give specific information about the actual object that is being clicked on the canvas.

Any ideas of the most FabricJS-y way of doing this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The more elegant way is to override `fabric.Canvas._initEventListeners` to add the dblclick support

```js
_initEventListeners: function() {
  var self = this;
  self.callSuper('_initEventListeners');

  addListener(self.upperCanvasEl, 'dblclick', self._onDoubleClick);
}
```

```js
_onDoubleClick: function(e) {
  var self = this;

  var target = self.findTarget(e);
  self.fire('mouse:dblclick', {
    target: target,
    e: e
  });

  if (target && !self.isDrawingMode) {
    // To unify the behavior, the object's double click event does not fire on drawing mode.
    target.fire('object:dblclick', {
      e: e
    });
  }
}
```

I've also developed a library to implement more events missed in fabricjs : https://github.com/mazong1123/fabric.ext

Comment: Jim, I'm getting "this.constructor.superclass is null" with the latest Fabric.js version 1.4.0. After Fabric.js is loaded I included `fabric.Canvas.prototype._initEventListeners = function() {...}` and `fabric.Canvas.prototype._onDoubleClick = function(e) {...}` in my own code. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @user2113581 , you should subclass fabric.Canvas to override _initEventListeners and _onDoubleClick instead of adding prototypes directly to fabric.Canvas object. See example: https://github.com/mazong1123/fabric.ext/blob/master/fabricext/scripts/fabric.canvasex.js

Comment: @JimMa I take it none of the fabric.ext stuff works any more (with FabricJS 2+)? I tried to use it wholesale, didn't seem to work. Is it a quick fix to upgrade? Your additions seem quite useful (although some of them have been baked into FabricJS directly now).

Answer (score 8):

This is similar to @LeoCreer's answer but actually gets access to the targeted object

```
fabric.util.addListener(canvas.upperCanvasEl, 'dblclick', function (e) {
  var target = canvas.findTarget(e);
});
```

Comment: How do i get subTargets ?

Answer (score 5):

The Correct way to add custom events to **Fabric.js**

```
window.fabric.util.addListener(canvas.upperCanvasEl, 'dblclick', function (event, self) {
  yourFunction(event);
});
```

or use [fabric.ext](https://github.com/mazong1123/fabric.ext)

Comment: How do i get subTargets ?

Answer (score 3):

I'm using this workaround:

```
  var timer = 0;
  canvas.item(0).on('mouseup', function() {
    var d = new Date();
    timer = d.getTime();
  });
  canvas.item(0).on('mousedown', function() {
    var d = new Date();
    if ((d.getTime() - timer) < 300) {
      console.log('double click')
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a quick and easy way to add a double click event handler to Fabric JS -

Include following code snippet to your html file. Just ensure this is loaded after the main fabric.js library

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        fabric = (function(f) { var nativeOn = f.on; var dblClickSubscribers = []; var nativeCanvas = f.Canvas;   f.Canvas = (function(domId, options) { var canvasDomElement = document.getElementById(domId); var c = new nativeCanvas(domId, options);   c.dblclick = function(handler) { dblClickSubscribers.push(handler) };   canvasDomElement.nextSibling.ondblclick = function(ev){ for(var i = 0; i < dblClickSubscribers.length; i++) { console.log(ev); dblClickSubscribers[i]({ e :ev }); } }; return c; });   return f; }(fabric)); 
</script>
```

Then add this code to listen a double click event:

```
canvas.dblclick(function(e) { 

});
```

To get information about the actual object that is being clicked on the canvas, use following method -

```
canvas.getActiveObject();
```

eg.

```
canvas.dblclick(function(e) { 
     activeObject = canvas.getActiveObject();
});
```

Comment: when i try and scale things i get an error saying _setscaleequal not defined

Answer (score 2):

I am late but now fabricjs has `mousedblclick` event.

Listed at: http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Object.html

See all events:
http://fabricjs.com/events

Comment: fabricObject.on("mousedblclick", ()=>{//your method here})