# Fabric.js dbclick event child element

Tags: jquery, fabricjs

I have a fabric element inside a canvas, and I want to add a dbclick event on that specific element.

```
customText = new fabric.Text(customTextContent, {
    pp_type: 'custom_text',
    pp_label: _t('my text'),
    // lockUniScaling: true,
    uniqId: uniqId,
    fill: customColor,
    fontFamily: customFont,
    fontSize: 12,
    scaleX: self.baseTextScale,
    scaleY: self.baseTextScale
});


customText.on('mouse:dblclick', function (e){
   console.log('canvas db clicked');
   console.log(e);
});
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Maybe you should use `addEventListener` like in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43898913/863110) answer?

Comment: I guess I can try yes, but I think this was how the things were done before the db click were supported by Fabricjs. So the dbclick shoudl work :/ 
Well may be I haven't the good version.

Comment: But in that answer the event is on the canvas and not on the object like `rect`.

Comment: I don't know. I'm not using fabric, although I was be able to help people with that (With the best debugging approach - Trial and error :) )

Comment: As I thought the method works to add the db click on the whole canvas, but doing this I don't know which specific element is db clicked so it's not really what i am looking for here.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23418055/863110) can help?

Comment: Oh actually the method findTarget can make the trick so it's all good.

Comment: Glad to hear :) Maybe you can answer to your own question for a future readers..

Comment: @MoshFeu You right it's done :)

Comment: on what version of fabric are you? i think it all boil down to that problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
window.fabric.util.addListener(canvas.upperCanvasEl, 'dblclick', function (e, self) {
    var target = canvas.findTarget(e);
}
```

Target wil contains all the specification of the clicked element. So just need to switch the bahavior considering the type or whatever the kind of condition you need.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the official docs/demos.

http://fabricjs.com/events

Here is explained that if you are listening for a generic double click event on the canvas you need to use:

```js
canvas.on('mouse:dblclick', eventHandler)
```

while if you are listening on objects:

```js
text.on('mousedblclick', eventHandler)
```

This is the old naming schema and has never been change to preserve backward compatibility where possible